# If $(A \overline{A} )^n = I$, then $A$ is diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

We know that $A^n = I$ implies that $A$ is a diagonalisable, as the minimum polynomial must have distinct roots.

I'm wondering if $(A \overline{A} )^m = A \overline{A} ... A \overline{A} = I$ implies that same?

If not then a quick counterexample would be appreciated!

Comment: Does $\bar{A}$ mean complex conjugation?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{A}$ means complex conjugation, I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I made a stupid mistake, here is an example.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1 \\
0 & i
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-i & 1 \\
0 & -i
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

**P.S.** The answer is trivially yes for real matrices.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Counterxample:
$$A=\pmatrix{1&i\\0&1}.$$